# C / Youtube API Request > VLC

Tags: c, json, youtube, decode

I'm trying to improve my tiny C application which streams YouTube videos.
For some reason I'm not being able to send request and decode JSON.
Could someone point me in the right direction, this is the original.

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define SA      struct sockaddr
#define MAXLINE 4096
#define LISTENQ 1024

void process_http(int sockfd, char argv[]){
  
    char sendline[MAXLINE], recvline[MAXLINE];
    char storeline[MAXLINE];
    char run_command[50];
    char * linkpos;
    ssize_t n;
    int arraysize;
    int i;
    
    arraysize = strlen(&argv[0]);

    if(&argv[0] == "\32") {
    
        printf("Har space\n");
    
    }  
    
    strcpy(sendline,"GET /?youtubereq=");
    strcat(sendline,&argv[0]);
    strcat(sendline," /HTTP/1.0\r\n");
    strcat(sendline,"Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n");
    strcat(sendline,"Pragma: no-cache\r\n");
    strcat(sendline,"Host: 127.0.0.1\r\n");
    strcat(sendline,"Accept: www/source\r\n");
    strcat(sendline,"Accept: text/html\r\n\r\n");
    write(sockfd, sendline, strlen(sendline));
   
    while ( ( n = read(sockfd, recvline, MAXLINE)) != 0 )
    {
        recvline[n]='\0';
        strcat(storeline, recvline);
    }
    linkpos = strstr(storeline, "http://www.youtube.com/");
    strcpy(run_command, "cvlc ");
    strcat(run_command, linkpos);
    system("clear");
    printf("Playing video...\n");
    system(run_command);
}

void encode(unsigned char *s, char *enc, char *tb)
{
    for (; *s; s++) {
        if (tb[*s]) sprintf(enc, "%c", tb[*s]);
        else        sprintf(enc, "%%%02X", *s);
        while (*++enc);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  int sockfd;
  struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
  char rfc3986[256] = {0};
  char html5[256] = {0};

  sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
  servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  servaddr.sin_port = htons(80);
  inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &servaddr.sin_addr);

  connect(sockfd, (SA *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

  char enc[sizeof(argv[1]) * 3];
 
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        rfc3986[i] = isalnum(i)||i == '~'||i == '-'||i == '.'||i == '_'
            ? i : 0;
        html5[i] = isalnum(i)||i == '*'||i == '-'||i == '.'||i == '_'
            ? i : (i == ' ') ? '+' : 0;
    }
   

  printf("Loading video, please wait...\n");
  encode(argv[1], enc, rfc3986);
  process_http(sockfd, enc);

  return 0; 
}
```

I'm currently relying on PHP/Apache to be run on localhost to do the API-Request for me, this is far from optimal. but as stated above can't seem to be able to implement that part in this code.

(I'm quite new to C)

The PHP Code is as follows.

```
<?php
if($_GET['youtubereq']) {
$req = $_GET['youtubereq'];
$req = urlencode($req);
$build_yt_url = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q='" . $req  . "'&format=5&max-results=1&v=2&alt=jsonc"; 

$response = file_get_contents($build_yt_url);
$response = json_decode($response, true);

$raw_url = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" . $response["data"]["items"][0]["id"];
echo $raw_url;
}
else {
echo ".";
}
?>
```

Program works like this ./youtubeplayer "some video to search for"

Ideas?

Comment: If you really want to use C to query the YouTube API, it would be better to use a json library. And try using some library like curl for the http request, it's simpler than using just the sockets api.

Comment: Already did it with the cURL library, moved on to sockets to learn it by just using C.

Comment: Json Library wasnt a bad idea though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're complicating. You can run php from the command line:

```
<?php
if ($argc != 2) die("wrong params\n");
$build_yt_url = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q='"
    . urlencode($argv[1]) . "'&format=5&max-results=1&v=2&alt=jsonc";

$response = file_get_contents($build_yt_url) or die("error fetching data\n");
$response = json_decode($response, true);

if (!isset($response["data"]["items"][0]["id"]))
    die("error finding in result\n");

$raw_url = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" .
        $response["data"]["items"][0]["id"];

system("cvlc " . escapeshellarg($raw_url));
```

Then run with:

```
php myscript.php cat
```